# KDB: parallel insertion to table

Tags: kdb

I created a multi-threaded connections from Java to KDB then have records inserted to a single table concurrently.

But it seems that the sum of the individual duration and the overall duration is almost the same as if no concurrent insertion happened.

Would you know if KDB supports parallel insertion? 
If so, is there any setting I should do?
Does it have a record-level or table-level locking?

Answer (score 4):

kdb does not support parallel inserts into in-memory tables. In fact updates to in-memory data may only be made from the q main thread. This means that tables are 'locked' (can't be amended) essentially to all clients if a q server is started with a negative port, and the issue is irrelevant if the q session is in single threaded mode (as most sessions tend to be). The situation is a little different for tables stored on disk (I can expand on that later if required).

In order to accelerate your inserts I would suggest looking at the following:

a) Are the inserts batched, rather than as a series of single inserts? One insert of 1k rows will take much less time that 1k inserts of one row.

b) Are the inserts sent async or sync? Changing between these two may speed up insertion rates but at the cost of knowing if the inserts executed correctly.

Can you share more about your use case? Is your Java client sending market data? if so would a TP style setup be more appropriate? See kdb+ tick and its derivatives such as TorQ (note that TorQ is developed by my employer).

Answer (score 2):

A KDB process is a single-threaded process in general (except when running in multiple slave thread/process mode) https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cmdline/#-s-slaves

Though you have multiple java threads writing data to q process, the data is getting written in KDB in a sequential manner, hence it is not giving any performance benefit. it does not need the table/row level locking due to this

though I would recommend that you stream the data in async mode (negative handle), this will let your java threads come quickly rather than waiting for KDB to complete the operation, this will definitely improve the performance at the writing side.

While using parallel processing mode(slave threads - positive number), the slave threads are not allowed writing to the global tables/variables; you would need to use multi-process mode to achive that(negative number while launching the q process)